# Remove/Unset default $colors in Bootstrap 4 (map-remove)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4, customization

I'm trying to unset/remove/delete default colors in Bootstrap 4.3.1. I've read the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#remove-from-map), applied what it says, but it doesn't work or I am not doing things well :(

I've tried this:

```
$colors: map-remove($colors, "blue", "indigo", "purple", "pink", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "teal", "cyan");
```

This is my code:

```
// Import resources
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";

//
// Color system
//
$crimson:     #E6312E;
$ecstasy:     #F67524;
$sun:         #F8B418;
$turbo:       #FEE600;
$atlantis:    #99C931;
$apple:       #64AD34;
$green-haze:  #00944E;
$heavy-metal: #1C1D1B;
$denim:       #1782B8;

$colors: map-merge(
  (
    "crimson":     $crimson,
    "ecstasy":     $ecstasy,
    "sun":         $sun,
    "turbo":       $turbo,
    "atlantis":    $atlantis,
    "apple":       $apple,
    "green-haze":  $green-haze,
    "denim":       $denim,
    "heavy-metal": $heavy-metal
  ),
  $colors
);

$colors: map-remove($colors, "blue", "indigo", "purple", "pink", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "teal", "cyan");

$primary:       $heavy-metal;
$success:       $apple;
$info:          $denim;
$warning:       $turbo;
$danger:        $crimson;

//
// Finally, import Bootstrap!
//
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

I expect that $colors only have my custom colors plus white, gray-600 and gray-800.

This is how I compile SASS with gulp:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var cache = require('gulp-cache');
var cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var notify = require('gulp-notify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var del = require('del');

var paths = {
    styles: {
        src: 'dev/src/scss/**/*.scss',
        dest: 'dist/css/',
        public: 'wp-content/themes/atipus/css/'
    }
};

sass.compiler = require('node-sass');

function clean() {
    return del([ 'assets' ]);
}

function styles() {
    return gulp.src(paths.styles.src)
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 3 versions'))
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(rename({
            basename: 'main',
            suffix: '.min'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.dest))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.styles.public));
}

function watch() {
    gulp.watch(paths.styles.src, styles);
}

var build = gulp.series(clean, gulp.parallel(styles));

exports.clean = clean;
exports.styles = styles;
exports.watch = watch;
exports.build = build;

exports.default = build;
```

Anyone know how to remove the Bootstrap default colors?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to change colors, or theme-colors? Are trying to create new theme colors so that you can use bg-sun, text-sun, border-sun, etc...?

Comment: I need to create new colors and theme-colors. I'm just beginning with colors, but the next step will be applying the solution to theme-colors.

Answer (score 0):

It's working as expected, the new `colors` are added. But, there is no way to see the new colors until you add them to `theme-colors` map...

```
$theme-colors: (
  "crimson": $crimson,
  "ecstasy": $ecstasy,
  "sun": $sun,
  "turbo": $turbo,
  ...
);
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/davKMdkCld

---

Also, make sure you define all you color vars *before* you import Bootstrap vars...

```
$crimson:     #E6312E;
$ecstasy:     #F67524;
$sun:         #F8B418;
$turbo:       #FEE600;
$atlantis:    #99C931;
$apple:       #64AD34;
$green-haze:  #00944E;
$heavy-metal: #1C1D1B;
$denim:       #1782B8;

$primary:   $heavy-metal;
$success:   $apple;
$info:      $denim;
$warning:   $turbo;
$danger:    $crimson;

@import "bootstrap/functions";
@import "bootstrap/variables";

$colors: map-merge(
  (
    "crimson":     $crimson,
    "ecstasy":     $ecstasy,
    "sun":         $sun,
    "turbo":       $turbo,
    "atlantis":    $atlantis,
    "apple":       $apple,
    "green-haze":  $green-haze,
    "denim":       $denim,
    "heavy-metal": $heavy-metal
  ),
  $colors
);
$colors: map-remove($colors, "blue", "indigo", "purple", "pink", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "teal", "cyan");

$theme-colors: (
  "crimson": $crimson,
  "ecstasy": $ecstasy,
  "sun": $sun,
  "turbo": $turbo
);

@import "bootstrap";
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/davKMdkCld

Comment: I inspected the code of your codeply example, and I continue seeing the default variables in the :root. Here an screenshoot: https://paste.pics/58NNC
I would like to erase these default colors and only have my custom colors in :root

Comment: In normal circumstance with a SASS complied they would be removed, but Codeply is re-adding the entire Bootstrap CSS. Please accept the answer so others know the question is solved.

Comment: First of all, I'm very grateful for your help. But I cannot accept answer because when I've tried it in my local computer, compiling SASS, I continue getting default color variables :( I've edited my initial question with the code I use to compile SASS. Thanks again!

Comment: And what about removing them with map-remove() not working?

Comment: Hi @ed1nh0! I tried `$colors: map-remove($colors, "blue", "indigo", "purple", "pink", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "teal", "cyan");` but it did not work :(

Comment: Yes indeed @hormigaz same here. Tried with $colors and $theme-colors, after and before (just for testing) calling required BS files... nothing!

Comment: @hormigaz I just made a test here and it actually works! But we're removing only the colors from the map(), the vars ($blue, $indigo, etc) are still there, that's why we're seeing all the CSS vars (--blue, --indigo, etc) in the browser inspector.

Comment: Maybe is not possible to do it... :( Maybe the brand new Bootstrap 5 will 'fix' this...

Answer (score 0):

I found a very easy solution to remove all default colors in bootstrap.

Instead of using like this

```
$colors: map-remove($colors, "blue", "indigo", "purple", "pink", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "teal", "cyan");
```

**Use it like this**

```
$colors: ();
```